# Which is the best opensource java libraries to login with Facebook & Google?

Tags: facebook, jsf, facebook-graph-api

Which is the best opensopurce java libraries to integrate login with Facebook, Google etc.

NOTE: if you know about the support for the specified libraries, would like to rate them based on that as well.

Comment: Hi @abh - As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

Comment: Yes I know and I completely agree to what you have to say but sometimes you need answers for these kind of questions and this forums seems to be the best place as people comment based on their experience which is quite important.

Comment: from my experience, the only answers you'll get are similar to the one already here - its too subjective and is very much dependant on time frames - answers here probably wont be relevant a few months down the line.   the objective here is to have questions and answers that'll be able to help people in the future and not just now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use RestFB, that seems to be the inofficial FB Java Api:

http://restfb.com/

Comment: RestFB is more about fetching data from Facebook. How to 'login with Facebook'